# Dictionary keyed on a property of the stored data

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

What is the easiest way to create a dictionary that will be keyed on a property of the data object? E.g. imagine I have:

```
interface A
{
  string Key{get;}
  //other stuff
}
```

So far I have:

```
IDictionary<string, A> dict = new Dictionary<string, A>();
void Add(A a)
{
  dict[a.Key] = a; //I would prefer that the collection class managed this relationship
}

A Get(string key)
{
  return dict[key];
}
```

Is there a nicer way to achieve the same? (the collection doesn't need to implement IDictionary, as long as it has the required indexer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`KeyedCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx):

```
public class MyCollection : KeyedCollection<string, A>
{
    protected override GetKeyForItem(A a)
    {
        return a.Key;
    }
}
```